# Plotly indicator gauge / speedometer displaying imperial and metric units at the same time

Tags: plotly, indicator, gauge

using Python Plotly I want to create a speedometer displaying the pressure in "bar" and "psi" at the same time. Displaying one unit at the same time is no problem. But I could not manage to have a second set of labels showing the other unit.

My target is that the speedometer shows the imperial unit outside and the metric unit inside. Basically similar from what you know from an American car speedometer which displays mph on the outside and the kmh a little smaller in the inside.

BTW: 1 bar is approx. 14.5 PSI)

Here is my code up to now:

```
     fig_pressure = go.Figure(
        go.Indicator(
          domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
          value = 450,
          number = {"suffix": "bar"},
          mode = "gauge+number",
          title = {'text': "Pressure"},
          gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, 5000]},
                  'steps' : [
                      {'range': [0, 330], 'color': "lightgreen"},
                      {'range': [330, 1500], 'color': "oranged"},
                    {'range': [1500, 5000], 'color': "purple"},
                  ],
                  }))
```